# Node.js - Using await new Promise in mysql pool connection - SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Node.js - Using await new Promise in mysql pool connection - SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

I'm trying to use a new promise inside a pool connection ... but I'm getting this SyntaxError: Unexpected token new. What am I missing?

Error:

```
let rowsPromise01 = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                              ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token new
```

js:

```
const pool = require('./config/dbpool');    

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) throw err;

   let rowsPromise01 = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM table01", function(err, rows) {
        //connection.release();
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Found records: '+rows.length);
          resolve(rows);       
        }
    });
   });

   let rowsPromise02 = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    connection.query(SELECT * FROM table02,function(err, results) {
      connection.release();
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
      console.log('Found records: '+result.length);
      resolve(results);
      }
    });

    });

});
```

The dbpool.js looks like this:

```
const mysql= require('mysql');

//database connection
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});

module.exports = {
  getConnection (callback) {
    pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
      if(err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      callback(err, conn);
    });
  },
  query (query, params=[], cb) {
    this.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        conn.release();
        if(err) return cb(err, null);
        conn.query(query, params, (err, res) => {
            if(err) return cb(err, null);
            return cb(null, res);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a bit of a red herring, the issue is really with the `await` keyword, which is only valid inside functions that are marked with `async`, which in your case is missing.

Fix:

```
pool.getConnection(async function(err, connection) { .... });
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description

Comment: The error is gone ... and it seems that the first query is going through ... but now I'm getting this error: Error: Connection already released . Can I not call connection.release(); twice like above?

Comment: @PhilippM no, it can only be released back to the pool once (a similar issue occurs in `dbpool.query`, where you release the connection before even using it for a query). Take a look at [`pool.query()`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections), which might be easier to use.

Comment: mmh ... I'm confused. I took the connection.release() out except in the last query but now I'm getting again { Error: read ECONNRESET at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11) at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25) for the second query which I also got when not using the pool connection

Comment: @PhilippM perhaps take a look at the MySQL logs to see why it's closing the connection.